# Generic repository on Entity Framework without "generics" technology

Tags: entity-framework, generics, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1

How can I build an Entity Framework repository which manages all kind of existing entities?

But I want to achieve this without using `generics`, because I'm going to build some generic CRUD WPF controls and I won't know the right entity while in "coding time", just in runtime?

Answer (score 1):

You can determine the EntitySetName of an object at run time by using the following code:

```
internal static EntitySetBase GetEntitySet<TEntity>(this ObjectContext context)
{
    EntityContainer container = context.MetadataWorkspace.GetEntityContainer(context.DefaultContainerName, DataSpace.CSpace);

    EntitySetBase entitySet = container.BaseEntitySets.Where(item => item.ElementType.Name.Equals(typeof(TEntity).Name))
                                                             .FirstOrDefault();

    return entitySet;
 }
```

The ObjectContext then has a method `AddObject(string entitySetName, Object entity)`([MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.addobject.aspx)).

Combining those you can create a Repository which you can pas an `object`, determine the entity set name and then add the object.

Comment: And what about the other CRUD operations? Restore (findAll, findById ...), Update, Delete.

Comment: @DiegoStiehl You would have to find the right ObjectSet trough reflection

Comment: Wouldn't you have a little example of code or an implemented sample class? Thanks.